# logcat is not displaying any logging for my programmes android

Tags: android, logcat

When I start eclipse and start the emulator, I can see the initial logging related to configurations and setting the environment of the emulator.But if I run any of my android app programs , logcat is not tracing a single line.

I have tried restarting it again and again but it does not help. Restarting eclipse is also not helping.What could be possible reason?? It was working fine yesterday.

===================================
Edit 1:-

Below I am pasting all the error messages that gets displayed when the emulator starts:-

```
10-13 16:47:15.497: ERROR/PhonePolicy(31): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
10-13 16:47:38.104: ERROR/BatteryService(73): usbOnlinePath not found
10-13 16:47:38.104: ERROR/BatteryService(73): batteryVoltagePath not found
10-13 16:47:38.104: ERROR/BatteryService(73): batteryTemperaturePath not found
10-13 16:47:38.144: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(73): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
10-13 16:47:48.817: ERROR/EventHub(73): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
10-13 16:47:48.817: ERROR/EventHub(73): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
10-13 16:47:49.344: ERROR/WifiService(73): Invoking mWifiStateMachine.setWifiEnabled
10-13 16:47:52.438: ERROR/ThrottleService(73): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
10-13 16:47:52.457: ERROR/NetworkTimeUpdateService(73): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
10-13 16:47:52.464: ERROR/NetworkTimeUpdateService(73): NTP server address not found, not syncing to NTP time
10-13 16:47:52.844: ERROR/logwrapper(142): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
10-13 16:47:53.064: ERROR/logwrapper(144): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
10-13 16:47:53.115: ERROR/logwrapper(147): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
10-13 16:48:05.364: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-13 16:48:05.514: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-13 16:48:05.535: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-13 16:48:05.555: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-13 16:48:05.624: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-13 16:48:05.684: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-13 16:48:05.704: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-13 16:48:05.755: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-13 16:48:05.764: ERROR/SoundPool(73): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73): Start proc com.android.email for broadcast com.android.email/.service.EmailBroadcastReceiver: pid=273 uid=10013 gids={3003, 1015}Load: 8.11 / 2.1 / 0.71
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73): CPU usage from 1368ms to -18166ms ago:
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   38% 73/system_server: 25% user + 12% kernel / faults: 8480 minor 2 major
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   7.8% 149/com.android.launcher: 7% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 1009 minor 6 major
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   6.7% 139/com.android.phone: 5.2% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 521 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   6.3% 40/adbd: 0.3% user + 5.9% kernel / faults: 20 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   5.8% 84/bootanimation: 4.8% user + 1% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   5.5% 124/com.android.systemui: 4.8% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 799 minor 2 major
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   4.3% 198/android.process.acore: 3.8% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 414 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   2.1% 31/zygote: 1.7% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 246 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   2% 214/com.android.mms: 1.3% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 793 minor 2 major
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   0.4% 154/android.process.media: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 20 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   0.2% 72/logcat: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   0% 38/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):  +0% 246/com.android.deskclock: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):  +0% 273/com.android.email: 0% user + 0% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73): 100% TOTAL: 68% user + 29% kernel + 0.8% irq + 1.2% softirq
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73): CPU usage from 15277ms to 16982ms later:
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   24% 73/system_server: 14% user + 10% kernel / faults: 109 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     10% 90/ActivityManager: 6.2% user + 3.8% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     7.6% 81/SurfaceFlinger: 4.3% user + 3.3% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     3.8% 103/WindowManagerPo: 3.8% user + 0% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     1.4% 223/Binder Thread #: 0.9% user + 0.4% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     1.4% 232/Binder Thread #: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.9% 78/Compiler: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.9% 79/Binder Thread #: 0.4% user + 0.4% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.9% 168/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.9% 240/Binder Thread #: 0.4% user + 0.4% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.9% 241/Binder Thread #: 0.4% user + 0.4% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.4% 73/system_server: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.4% 104/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.4% 173/Binder Thread #: 0.4% user + 0% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.4% 208/Thread-62: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.4% 242/Binder Thread #: 0.4% user + 0% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   9.9% 31/zygote: 9.3% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 43 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   9.4% 149/com.android.launcher: 7.8% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 69 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     8.9% 149/ndroid.launcher: 8.3% user + 0.5% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.5% 153/HeapWorker: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.5% 178/launcher-loader: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   8.6% 40/adbd: 0% user + 8.6% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     5.5% 265/adbd: 0% user + 5.5% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     4.3% 40/adbd: 0.6% user + 3.7% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     1.8% 65/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     0.6% 64/adbd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   8.4% 273/com.android.email: 7.2% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 237 minor 1 major
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     8.4% 273/m.android.email: 7.2% user + 1.2% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   6.1% 84/bootanimation: 5.6% user + 0.5% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     9.2% 89/BootAnimation: 8.2% user + 1% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   6.1% 124/com.android.systemui: 4.4% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 62 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     13% 124/ndroid.systemui: 11% user + 2.2% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     1.1% 125/HeapWorker: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     1.1% 130/Compiler: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):   2.1% 139/com.android.phone: 1.5% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1 minor
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73):     3.1% 140/HeapWorker: 2.6% user + 0.5% kernel
10-13 16:48:31.622: ERROR/ActivityManager(73): 100% TOTAL: 66% user + 30% kernel + 1.3% irq + 1.3% softirq
10-13 16:48:31.763: ERROR/TelephonyManager(73): Hidden constructor called more than once per process!
10-13 16:48:31.763: ERROR/TelephonyManager(73): Original: android, new: android
10-13 16:48:32.172: ERROR/InputDispatcher(73): channel '414c4c20 NotificationPanel (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-13 16:48:32.172: ERROR/InputDispatcher(73): channel '414c4c20 NotificationPanel (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-13 16:48:32.502: ERROR/InputDispatcher(73): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=178, events=0x8
10-13 16:48:32.502: ERROR/InputDispatcher(73): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=176, events=0x8
10-13 16:48:32.502: ERROR/InputDispatcher(73): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=189, events=0x8
```

Comment: @Falmarri r u serious?? :) it was working on all thursdays earlier ;)

Comment: After doing restarting of eclipse multiple times it has started working.Though still I have no clues that why the logcat behaved in such a strange way.

Comment: try clean building the project's or try changing workspace folder

Comment: First, check with the command line with `adb logcat`, then give up Eclipse and start using http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stops working if the adb gets killed from the memory. If you see similar problem,
close logcat and on command prompt, type,

adb kill-server

and restart the eclipse. I bet it will work then.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you need to restart adb you can do it from Eclipse as well. In the DDMS perspective, select the device and in the device view, select the view menu (down arrow, next to the Camera icon) and the **Reset adb**.